# Selenium driver not able to access some elements when maximized and minimized

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, maximize-window

Using selenium I am able to access some elements when browser is maximised and minimised

I tried with different add_argument options and found that elements are not accessible due to the size of window.

```
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
```

Above are the options that I added, when I comment out some parts of the code works (clicking on next page) but I am not able to access elements once maximized (by uncommenting the above code).